# Oracle Password File Version

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

When trying to perform certain user security actions, I get the following error:

`ORA-46953: The password file is not in the 12.2 format.`

How do I migrate a 12.1 password file to 12.2? Or, is this even necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can migrate the password file with the `input_file` option of `orapwd`.

Example:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ orapwd file=test format=12

Enter password for SYS:
[oracle@o71 ~]$ orapwd describe file=test
Password file Description : format=12
[oracle@o71 ~]$ orapwd file=test2 input_file=test format=12.2
[oracle@o71 ~]$ orapwd describe file=test2
Password file Description : format=12.2
```

Comment: Excellent! Now (being new at Oracle DBA), how do I locate the password file?

Comment: Darrell what operation fails, the password file might be listed in the Listener.ora File, in the client connection string or the client connection properties.

Comment: @Darrell The password file is located by default in `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` on Linux/UNIX platforms and `%ORACLE_HOME%\database` on Windows. If the database is configured with Grid Infrastructure, the password file can be at a custom location, which you can view with `srvctl config database -d DB_UNIQUE_NAME` where `DB_UNIQUE_NAME` is the unique name of the database.

Comment: @eckes No, the password file is not listed at any of those locations.

Comment: @BalazsPapp yes Right, the Location of wallets are there, the password file is not.

Comment: Found it. Thanks to @Balazs.